# How to add , update and delete Many2many field records in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo

I am setting up function in a wizard which will do following actions:

1. Add new record and linked to current existing `Many2many` Field.
2. Update record of current existing `Many2many` Field.
3. Delete current existing `Many2many` Field.
   Wizard model and Actual model having two `Many2many` fields
4. `customers_ids = fields.Many2many('res.partners', 'Customers')`
5. `new_customers_ids = fields.Many2many('res.partners', 'New Customers')`

In View Customers_ids are read only view where as `new_customers_ids` allowing add item (customer) and delete.

When I am adding new customers `new_customers_ids` from view but can't now updating `customers_ids`(Customers ids) via clicking button *save* on wizard.
How can add/ delete and update records from `customers_ids`  via adding/ deleting and updating in `new_customers_ids` ?

```
 @api.multi 
def applychanges(self):

    for record in self:
        customers = []
        new_customers = []
        for customer in record.customers_ids:
            customers.append(customer.id)
        customers = list(set(customers))

        for x in record.new_customers_ids:
            new_customers.append(x.id)
        new_customers = list(set(new_customers_ids))
    
        record.customers_ids = [(1, 0, new_customers)]
```

Answer (score 14):

Per [the ORM documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#openerp-models-relationals-format), using a left operator of `1` should be used as:

> (1, id, values)

And it effectively

> Updates an existing record of id `id` with the values in values.

---

In your code, you are using `(1, 0, values)` which is trying to update the record of `id == 0`, which can't possibly exist.

For what it's worth, I've rarely seen the left operator used as `1`. Usually, I use `4` to update the record value, which will add the `new_customer` to the `record`'s `customer_ids` field:

```
record.customers_ids = [(4, 0, new_customers[0])]
```

However, using `4` only supports adding one record at a time (which is why I used `new_customers[0]` in the above example. If you want to add many at once, you can use list comprehension:

```
record.customers_ids = [(4, 0, new_customer) for new_customer in new_customers]
```

---

For completeness, here is the snippet from the documentation with the purpose and syntax of each possible left operator. For reference, I've almost only ever used `3`, `4`, or `6`.

> **(0, _, values)**
>
> Adds a new record created from the provided value dict.
>
> **(1, id, values)**
>
> Updates an existing record of id `id` with the values in
>   `values`. Can not be used in `create()`.
>
> **(2, id, _)**
>
> Removes the record of id `id` from the set, then deletes it (from the database). Can not be used in `create()`.
>
> **(3, id, _)**
>
> Removes the record of id id from the set, but does not delete it. Can not be used on `One2many`. Can not be used in `create()`.
>
> **(4, id, _)**
>
> Adds an existing record of id `id` to the set. Can not be used on `One2many`.
>
> **(5, _, _)**
>
> Removes all records from the set, equivalent to using the command `3` on every record explicitly. Can not be used on `One2many`. Can not be used in `create()`.
>
> **(6, _, ids)**
>
> Replaces all existing records in the set by the `ids` list, equivalent
>   to using the command `5` followed by a command `4` for each `id` in `ids`.

Comment: Facing this issue 

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' On applied this code:


 @api.multi 
def applychanges(self):

    for record in self:
        customers = []
        new_customers = []
        for customer in record.customers_ids:
            customers.append(customer.id)
        customers = list(set(customers))

        for x in record.new_customers_ids:
            new_customers.append(x.id)
        new_customers = list(set(new_customers_ids))

        record.customers_ids = [(4, customers, new_customers)]

Comment: When you are using `4`, you can only add one `id` at a time. It is giving `unhashable ype: list` because it is expecting an integer. You are using `record.customers_ids = [(4, customers, new_customers)]`, where `customers` is a `list` and `new_customers` is a list - that won't work. Correct usage for adding one `customer_id` would look like: `[(4, customer_id)]` where `customer_id` is an integer. If you want to add multiple customers at once, you should use: `record.customers_ids = [(4, new_customer_id) for new_customer_id in new_customers]`.