# Odoo tree view only show one record with compute

Tags: treeview, odoo, record, display

I'm trying to display a user signed documents (from the "Sign app") on his page, so I added this to the inherited model:

```
    x_signatures_relation = fields.One2many("signature.request.item", "partner_id")
    x_signatures = fields.One2many("signature.request", compute="_get_signed_documents")

    @api.one
    def _get_signed_documents(self):
        ids = []
        for signature in self.x_signatures_relation:
            ids.append(signature.signature_request_id)
        self.x_signatures = ids
```

"signature.request.item" is the table relating the partner (user) with "signature.request" the actual signature.
However this return an empty view even though the current user has two signatures, but if I replace :

```
self.x_signatures = ids
```

with :

```
self.x_signatures = ids[0]
```

or :

```
self.x_signatures = ids[1]
```

It displays the record, so what's going on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odoo has a very specific set of rules about how you are "allowed" to manipulate `One2many` and `Many2Many` fields.

See [my recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54082418/3330552), which gives a detailed explanation of all options and when/how to use them. The Odoo [documentation also explains it](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#openerp-models-relationals-format) as well.

In your case, you are setting the value in a compute method, so you want to completely replace any existing values.

```
# Instead of 
# self.x_signatures = ids
# Try this, which uses the special number 6 to mean
# "replace any existing ids with these ids"
self.x_signatures = [(6, 0, ids)]
```

Furthermore, you could simplify your compute method:

```
@api.one
def _get_signed_documents(self):
    self.x_signatures = [(6, 0, self.x_signatures_relation.ids)]
```