# Odoo - Compute field working on local but not online

Tags: javascript, field, odoo, local

I have a custom field on the partner model that will get all signatures records (from the Sign app) concerning the current partner, here is my code :

```
# Signatures
x_signatures_relation = fields.One2many("signature.request.item", "partner_id")
x_signatures = fields.One2many("signature.request", compute="_get_signed_documents")

@api.multi
def _get_signed_documents(self):
    for record in self:
        record.x_signatures = [(6, 0, record.x_signatures_relation.ids)]
```

And this in the xml part :

```
<page string="Signatures" name="signatures">
                    <tree>
                        <field name="x_signatures" />
                    </tree>
                </page>
```

The code works perfectly as expected on my local machine, but once I push It through Github to odoo.sh, I get this error when I visit a partner with one signature at least (doesn't happen with partners with no signatures) :

```
Error:
TypeError: val is undefined

https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/3826-7bbc86b/web.assets_backend.js:1264
Traceback:
_parseServerData/<@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/3826-7bbc86b/web.assets_backend.js:1264:545
_.forEach@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:12:558
_parseServerData@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/3826-7bbc86b/web.assets_backend.js:1264:288
_readMissingFields/</<@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/3826-7bbc86b/web.assets_backend.js:1275:445
_.forEach@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:12:558
_readMissingFields/<@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/3826-7bbc86b/web.assets_backend.js:1275:35
then/</</<@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:802:678
fire@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:796:281
fireWith@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:801:198
Deferred/</deferred[tuple[0]]@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:803:56
rpc/</<@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:3869:346
then/</</<@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:802:678
fire@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:796:281
fireWith@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:801:198
Deferred/</deferred[tuple[0]]@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:803:56
fire@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:796:281
fireWith@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:801:198
then/</</<@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:802:874
fire@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:796:281
fireWith@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:801:198
then/</</<@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:802:874
fire@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:796:281
fireWith@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:801:198
done@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:1192:86
callback@https://keydigital-tb-import-test-258937.dev.odoo.com/web/content/1751-3ead7e4/web.assets_common.js:1212:15
```

If I remove the xml part, It displays the partner correctly, otherwise I wouldn't be able to find out where the problem is coming from since the stack trace is not really helping, any ideas ?

Comment: The error is solved in @sfx or @CZoellner answers, but I advice you to add the decorator `@api.depends('x_signatures_relation')` to your compute method as the computation of `x_signatures` field depends on it. I guess you have an explanation for that, but, you are telling Odoo to use IDs of `signature.request.item` model in `signature.request` model. Some kind of inheritance by delegation? It is a bit risky, though.

Comment: @forvas Actually the error is not solved, I'm still facing the same problem when I push the new code to odoo.sh, and the weird part is that both the old & new version of the xml code are working perfectly on my local machine but not on odoo online

Comment: Is your XML `page` element inside a XML `notebook` element? What is weird is that your old code is working OK in your local machine. Update your module in local to reload all your XML code (through terminal or interface), and see if it is still correct. Also remove the `tree` tags surrounding your One2many field and see what happens.

Comment: @forvas Yes the page is inside a notebook element since I'm inheriting the base.view_partner_form view to display the signature in the contact page, and no with removing the tree, updating the app & even restarting the service I get no error on my local machine, yet the same Javascript error displays online :/

Comment: Try to load your online instance with debug and assets on and debug the JS error yourself with your browsers development tools. These JS errors are the worst errors you can get in Odoo development.

Comment: @CZoellner Seems like a python error, I just don't know what's with the weird traceback, anyways I switched to a previous version of the code, where I had a different problem (It used to show just 1 record), and with the help of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54247651/5483425 I switched to the current code, but did not notice that It's not working on online until today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved It by editing the Python code as follow :

```
@api.depends('x_signatures_relation')
@api.multi
def _get_signed_documents(self):
    for record in self:
        ids = []
        for signature in record.x_signatures_relation:
            ids.append(signature.signature_request_id.id)
        record.x_signatures = [(6, 0, ids)]
```

Still I have no idea why the first piece of code did not work on odoo.sh and worked perfectly on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is enough

```
<page string="Signatures" name="signatures">
     <field name="x_signatures">
         <tree>
            <field name='your_filed_name'/>
            <field name='your_filed_name_2'/> 
         </tree>
     </field>
</page>
```

Comment: New code: 
    <page string="Signatures" name="signatures">
                        <field name="x_signatures">
                            <tree>
                                <field name="reference"/>
                                <field name="template_id"/>
                                <field name="state"/>
                                <field name="__last_update"/>
                                <field name="progress" widget="progressbar" options="{'max_field': '100'}"/>
                            </tree>
                        </field>
                    </page>

Comment: Sorry about the miss above, anyway It still gives the same Javascript error :/

Answer (score 1):

[The answer of sfx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54359964/3146213) should be enough, but i want to share more about your mistake.

```xml
<page string="Signatures" name="signatures">
    <tree>
        <field name="x_signatures" />
    </tree>
</page>
```

(I guess) You're trying to tell Odoo to show the signatures as list view. That's not necessary, as the other answer already is telling you. But the real mistake here is using `<tree>` hierachical above the field, which should be shown as a list subview.

You have to use `<tree>` (or `<kanban>`) within a field you want to show as subview. And then it's not enough to just define an empty subview, but a subview with fields, labels, and so on:

```xml
<page string="Signatures" name="signatures">
    <field name="x_signatures">
        <tree>
            <field name="field_1" />
            <field name="field_2" />
            <field name="field_n" />
        </tree>
    </field>
</page>
```

Comment: I edited the code, please check out the new version in my comment to @sfx , but It stills give the same Javascript error :/ It's very weird because both my old & new version of the code work on my local machine but not on odoo.sh

Comment: Then it must be another error. I don't have experience with odoo.sh, so i dont know how to get a better stacktrace.

Comment: Okay, I hope someone has an idea on what's going on, thank you for your time.